# Do EF nested queries run in separate threads?

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am creating a complex structure with EF 4.1.  A very simplified version looks like:

```
var top = from x in _context.top
          select new TopView 
          {
            field = top.field,
            sub = ( from y in x.RelatedTable
                    select new SubView
                    {
                      subfield = y.subfield,
                      subsub = ( from z in y.AnotherRelatedTable
                                 select new SubSubView
                                 {
                                   subsubfield = z.subsubfield
                                 }
                               )
                    }
                  )
          }
```

The viewmodels look like:

```
public class TopView {
   string field { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<SubView> sub { get; set; }
}

public class SubView {
   string subfield { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<SubSubView> sub { get; set; }
}

public class SubSubView {
   string subsubfield { get; set; }
}
```

When I retrieve a TopView object in my controller (but don't access any of the properties, after a few seconds, my output shows:

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1b44) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1448) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xf34) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Now, when I remove the inner-most structure so that SubView looks like:

```
                    select new SubView
                    {
                      subfield = y.subfield
                    }
```

And re-run, I only get two of the exit messages.

Does each nested query run in its own thread?  Are the messages something to worry about?

Answer (score 1):

> Does each nested query run in its own thread?

No.

> Are the messages something to worry about?

No.

What you should worry about is the [N+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem).

Comment: Can you explain where these messages are coming from, and why it's safe to ignore them?

Comment: @chris, I presume that you are seeing those messages in the Visual Studio debugger. It shows all threads. When you are working on a multithreaded application such as ASP.NET and run in debug mode, VS will trace all threads and in a multithreaded application you have lots of threads involved to service the requests. They all indicate return code of 0 meaning that those threads completed successfully doing whatever they were supposed to do (I guess service your worker requests), so you can safely ignore them.